# How can I change the first class name of my <html> and leave other classes as is?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<html class="black abc"> or 
<html class="red def"> or
<html class="red this is a test">
etc ...
```

Using the following function I can get the value 
of the first class:

```
var color = html.className.split(' ')[0]
```

How can I change the first class to something else.
For example how could I change:

```
<html class="black abc">

to

<html class="red abc">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className.split(' '); //Get a list of tags.
tags[0] = 'foo'; //Change the 0th tag
html.className = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].join(' '); //Put the tag list into the html
```

Comment: Will this add the spaces between classes also?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var classList = tags.className.split(' '); //Converting class string to an array
classList[0] = 'red'; // Changing the first class
tags.className = classList.join(' '); // Adding updated class list
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this (Just needs to change the class attribute of any html element)

You can do this with JQuery also ,

```
$("ID_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT").removeClass('PREVIOUS_CLASS').addClass('NEW_CLASS');
```

There are also other options available to do this JQuery supports [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: this is not a jquery question

Comment: @om_deshpande I know but 
I answered because wanted to give more options to do the same with different ways.

Comment: You should generally post only pure-js answers on something not tagged jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Using classList

**Removing Class**

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.remove("black");
```

**Adding Class**

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.add("red");
```

Comment: are you sure this is a cross-browser solution?

Comment: @om_deshpande not a cross-browser solution unless your audience is up-to-date ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)), but it is the *best* general solution to the problem of modifying only a single class name on an element.

Comment: No IE 9 support? Can't really get far with that.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function as follows in `<head>`'s `<script>`-section:

```
function class_replace_with(new_classname)
{
    var color1=html.className.split(' ')[0];
    html.className=html.className.substring(0, html.className.indexOf(' ')) + new_classname + html.className.substring(html.className.indexOf(' '));
}
```

So for your specific purpose call the function as:

```
class_replace_with('red');// as you have used red as the replacement for black.
```